# What is the use of X- path in selenium web driver?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath, automated-tests

Right now i am working on selenium web driver. I am learning new things in selenium. Currently i am stuck in my work with x-Path use. 
Can anyone describe me what is the use of x-path in selenium?
How we can use this in selenium web driver?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean? Of course, xPath is used to select elements....

Comment: I want to know about x -path usage in selenium web driver. How we can use that in selenium web driver?

Comment: What have you tried so far? There are tons of tutorials and questions here on SO covering this topic

Answer (score 0):

XPath contains the path of the element situated at the web page. Standard syntax for creating XPath is.
[Check this for more detail](https://www.guru99.com/xpath-selenium.html)

Answer (score 0):

I go through many links related to x-path. I understood that how we can use x-path in selenium. x-path is used to find elements in web page. when elements are not found by id, class than we use x-path for finding elements.

Answer (score 0):

XPath is defined as XML path. It is a syntax or language for finding any element on the web page using XML path expression. XPath is used to find the location of any element on a webpage using HTML DOM structure.

Examples:

```
//*[@id="id"]/a

//*[@id="panel"]/div/widget-header/header/span/widget-toolbar[1]/div/button

//*[@id="search-form"]/div/widget-body/div/form/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/label/input
```

using XPath to locate and perform operation:

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("")).Click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Xpath is an option you can use to locate an WebElement you wish to interact with.

As shown here:
https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/09_selenium_ide.jsp#locating-by-xpath

Answer (score 0):

xpath is one of the way to find out webelement of DOM.If you are not able to find out uniq id, name or other attributes of element in DOM then you can reach there element by xpath. by using different way through that element's parent, preceding sibling, following siblings. you can refer so much material on internet regarding this topic.